# Macro to create activex command button and assign a macro to that button

Tags: excel, activex, private, vba

i need a help here, i'm creating a code and one of it's functions will be to create a activeX command button but i need the code to create the button and assign the macro "Sub graft()" to it

So i need the macro to create the activeX button "Commandbutton1" and assign the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
Call graft()    
End sub
```

i know how to create the button, but i can't find how to assign a code to it the button will be created on a worksheet called "Gráfico" on the ActiveWorkbook

Code of creation and placement of the button

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=1200, Top:=20, _
Width:=100, Height:=30).Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("CommandButton1")).Select
Selection.Cut
Cells(lline + 26, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Where on Grafico are you wanting to place it?

Comment: @PJRosenburg i've updated the description with the code that i used to create the buttons, and place them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.  You will have to modify your code a little, but this places the button where your code is placing it, gives the button a caption, and assigns the macro "graft" to it.

Using With to avoid select statements, then assign the properties of the command button however you see fit.

```
Sub CreateButton()

    Dim newButton As Object 
    Set newButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1200, 20, 100, 30)

    With newButton
        .OnAction = "graft"
        .Caption = "Graft"
    End With

End Sub
```